# JPA Hibernate enum many to many

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to create 2 User entities as my application is starting that have a Role field which is a collection of enums.  One of the Users has two roles and the other has one role.  The enum doesn't have a corresponding table but there is a join table called USER_AUTHORITY_ROLES. The two Users are created in two different spring beans.  The field in the User class looks like this

```
@OrderColumn
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private List<AuthorityRole> authorityRoles = new ArrayList<AuthorityRole>();
```

When I just create one user it works fine, however when I create 2 users hibernate only saves one entry for each user in the USER_AUTHORITY_ROLES table, the same role.
I create one of the users roles like this

```
user.setAuthorityRoles(Arrays.asList(AuthorityRole.ROLE_ADMIN, AuthorityRole.ROLE_USER));
```

If I try to create the other user's roles using `Arrays.asList` hibernate complains about that collection being unmodifiable.

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:161) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.remove(AbstractList.java:374) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.AbstractList.removeRange(AbstractList.java:571) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.AbstractList.clear(AbstractList.java:234) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.replaceElements(CollectionType.java:543) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.replace(CollectionType.java:697) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.replace(TypeHelper.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.copyValues(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:407) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsPersistent(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:876) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:858) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:863) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1196) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
```

It seems like hibernate will only let me have one role(the same role) assigned to each user. Why would this be the case?

**Update:**
When both collections are made with `ArrayList` I'm having the same problem. In the join table the user that should have 2 roles only has one.

Comment: I'll admit that I'm a bit confused but the issue is that Arrays.toList() is returning an unmodifiable list.  Try to create the role list as just an ArrayList manually and see if it works better.

Comment: If I create the list as an ArrayList for the user with one role it doesn't throw an exception but removes one of the roles from my user that has 2 roles, even though I'm creating that list with Arrays.toList

Answer (score 0):

It is because of your

```
user.setAuthorityRoles(Arrays.asList(AuthorityRole.ROLE_ADMIN, AuthorityRole.ROLE_USER));
```

creates an unmodifiable list. Hibernate expects a modifiable list. Try using this instead and see if you can add 2 roles:

```
List<AuthorityRole> list = new ArrayList<AuthorityRole>();
list.add(AuthorityRole.ROLE_ADMIN);
list.add(AuthorityRole.ROLE_USER);    
user.setAuthorityRoles(list);
```

If not check if you did't create any additional relationship between tables in DB or you specified cascade somewhere in models.

Comment: Hibernate only complains about the unmodifiable list if both lists are unmodifiable. The list consists of enums which don't have corresponding tables